# Initializing state in constructor in React Component that uses generic state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is React + Typescript issue.
I'm having a component that uses two generics for props and state.

```
interface Props {
    foo: string;
}
interface State {
    bar: string;
}
class Foo<
    P extends Props = Props,
    S extends State = State
> extends React.Component<P, S> {
    constructor(props: P) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { bar: "asd" };
    }
}
```

The assigment to `this.state` in constructor is found to be an error with message:

> Type '{ bar: "asd"; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly(S)'

When you remove the generic from class declaration and pass `State` interface directly to `React.Component<P, State>` the everything is OK.

My question is how to avoid such error ? I need to initialize state in such manner that will validate known state parameters (like bar in this example) but will allow to specify additional properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Juraj Kocan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56583711/6802223) wrote in his answer. The problem is created because:

> you try to initialize generic type, this is wrong since you can extend this type and initialization won't be correct

Meanwhile I found that I can deal with it by spreading state in constructor:

```
interface Props {
    foo: string;
}
interface State {
    bar: string;
}
class Foo<
    P extends Props = Props,
    S extends State = State
> extends React.Component<P, S> {
    constructor(props: P) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { ...this.state, bar: "asd" };
    }
}
```

You can also do it without constructor:

```
interface Props {
    foo: string;
}
interface State {
    bar: string;
}
class Foo<
    P extends Props = Props,
    S extends State = State
> extends React.Component<P, S> {
   state:S = { ...this.state, bar: "asd" };
}
```

The latter solution was even better because spreading this.state in constructor made other errors appear where I used [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper). Spreading in constructor made TypeScript lose track of index properties in update() function of immutability-helper.

Answer (score 1):

you try to initialize generic type, this is wrong since you can extend this type and initialization won't be correct

example:

```
const instance = new Foo<Props, { otherRequiredProperty: string } & State>({ foo: '' });
cosnt otherProperty = instance.state.otherRequiredProperty
```

so i said that state type will have 2 required props but in your class you initialized with only bar...

you can create interface with required props and other optional if this is your point

```
interface Props {
  foo: string;
}

interface State {
  bar: string;
  [key: string]: string;
}

export class Foo extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bar: '',
    };

    this.setState({
      anything: '', // no error
    }); 
  }
}
```

this will not throw error and you can still add another property in to your state

Comment: Good clue. Thank you for clearing out. But i need to have generics because this is for my library code and I want users to be able to define specific interfaces for state and props.

I've just found that I can deal with this problem by using spread operator in constructor like this:

`this.state = { ...this.state, bar: "asd" };`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class Foo extends React.PureComponent<P, S> {
    state: State; //Add this line

    constructor(props: P) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { bar: "asd" };
    }
}
```